Make sure that only one transaction updates a row
I have users table
CREATE TABLE tasks(
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    status TEXT REFERENCES statuses, -- available statuses are 'NEW', 'PENDING', 'PROCESSING', 'COMPLETE'
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

I want to make sure that only single process will change status from PENDING to PROCESSING in case of multiple concurrent updates attempts, the rest should observe zero updated rows.
Task status change is driven by processing external HTTP request, it is important to only single request result in success, the rest should detect change and return 409 Conflict, we don't have control over how many concurrent request we can get.
Update statement is first thing that is done as part of bigger transaction, after update in case process observe that it updated tasks row (updated row count is 1), it later insert/update some data in other tables etc.
I've tested following update query
UPDATE tasks 
  SET status = 'PROCESSING'
  WHERE id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND status = 'PENDING'

using Java JDBC, multiple threads, connections etc. and I observe that only single process make update when using default isolation level READ COMMITTED.
When I was thinking about this problem I thought I need either FOR UPDATE in UPDATE statement or SERIALIZABLE isolation level on transaction, but in actual tests I wasn't able to catch inconsistency in case of multiple updates.
My question: is it enough to filter by id and status to make sure only single process will perform update, or I need additional actions to exclude unexpected behaviour in general?


is it enough to filter by id and status to make sure only single process will perform update?

Yes.
With the default isolation level READ COMMITTED, the first transaction to update the row write-locks it. Until that transaction is committed, concurrent transactions will still see status = 'PENDING' for the given id. But the row is write-locked, any transaction that wants to write to it has to wait until the lock is released. That happens when the locking transaction commits or rolls back. Then waiting transactions will, in turn, re-evaluate filters and see the new state status = 'PROCESSING' - and come up empty, which seems to be exactly what you want.
Waiting only makes sense for your particular query if the waiting transaction might find the row unchanged (still pending) once the lock is released, which only happens in case of ROLLBACK - or if different operations might have write-locked the row.
If you'd rather not wait, use SKIP LOCKED or NOWAIT. See:

Writing a query that will quit if there's a lock on a target row


Thanks for explanation!
I was thinking about SKIP LOCKED but tasks table has also other properties that can be updated independently, in case it isn't possible to distinguish "lock because I want update status" from "lock because I want update description" I think SKIP LOCKED won't be an option here to avoid cases when status isn't changed when concurrently we have description update.
I think to solve it I would need advisory lock for each taskId, column pair, or there is sth that allow distinguish to not wait for lock acquired to update different column?

@sebarys There is  certainly nothing in the UPDATE or SELECT ... FOR UPDATE syntax to distinguish.
